# How to setup allure for selenium +TestNG+java project?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, allure

I used extent report with java selenium for the automation testing but I would like to try allure reporting. Can anyone please explain to me how to setup Allure+ TestNG+ selenium in eclipse for automation?
Does it supports only maven based projects or even for java projects as well we can do it? Thanks

There is no pom.xml file in my current java project ...so this is a doubt if I can implement

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple. If you don't have a pom that means you are possibly using ant to build your tests. That's not an issue. What you can do is, download the allure .jar file. Add it to your project and off you go. With allure, there is no setup required. You will, however, need to implement annotations in your classes where you would like allure yo log things.

Here is an example :

Allure will then log your tests and steps as you would suspect natively. If you want screenshots and all the other goodies you would need to implement it. The docs can help with this part.

[image]

Here is the link to the jar file for allure - https://jar-download.com/artifact-search/allure-testng

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using pom, then based on latest version which is available at the time  you need following JAR files to be added in build path of your project in eclipse .

In my example I would be using version 2.9.0

1. allure-testng-2.9.0.jar
2. allure-model-2.9.0.jar
3. allure-java-commons-2.9.0.jar
4. allure-descriptions-javadoc-2.9.0.jar
5. sl4j-api-1.x.x.jar

Finally you need **allure-commandline-2.9.0.zip** .choose same version which you have downloaded above files.
Extract and set the path as described in the link -https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_manual_installation

Hope It helps! Thanks